# custom cmake FindXXX.cmake fallback to default location

Tags: cmake

I am trying to load OpenSSL as an external package. My issue is that the most recent version of  OpenSSL requires cmake 3.1.2 to use the default FindOpenSSL.cmake.

http://public.kitware.com/Bug/bug_relationship_graph.php?bug_id=15386&graph=relation

Is there a way to make a custom FindOpenSSL.cmake that just has
cmake_minimum_version(VERSION 3.1.2) and then a command to load the default FindOpenSSL?

I only want my package to fail to build with cmake_version<3.1.2 if the user chooses the optional dependency on OpenSSL.

Edit:This hacky FindOpenSSL.cmake works, but id still like something more idiomatic

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.2)
SET(TEMP_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "")
find_package(OpenSSL)
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${TEMP_PATH})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just copy from the latest CMake version the file Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake to your project and rename it to FindOpenSSLnew.cmake.

Dependent from the CMake version, you call the file from CMake or your copy:

```
if(CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_GREATER "3.1.2")
   Find(OpenSSL)
else()
   Find(OpenSSLnew)
endif()
```